# Running IBM Db2 DDL statements in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I need to alter a Db2 column using JDBC. The column may change its name and/or its type. In Db2 these two actions are done in two steps, the first ALTER TABLE to change the name, and the second ALTER TABLE to change the type.

For example:

```
    ALTER TABLE T1 RENAME COLUMN C1 TO C2;
    ALTER TABLE T1 ALTER COLUMN C2 SET DATA TYPE decimal(4,0);
```

See below the code, the first statement is executed but the second always throws an exception.

```
    String sql = "ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " RENAME COLUMN " + 
                    originalName + " TO " + name;
            
    PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps1.executeUpdate();
            
    sql = "ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " ALTER COLUMN " + name + 
                " SET DATA TYPE decimal(" + sc.getLength() + "," + sc.getDec() + ")";

    PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps2.executeUpdate();
```

The exception is:

> The operation was not performed because the table is in an invalid
> state for the operation. Table name: "DB.T1".
> Reason code: "23".. SQLCODE=-20054, SQLSTATE=55019, DRIVER=4.27.25

What is the meaning of a table in an "invalid state"? Why is the table in this state? What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Is the original column referenced anywhere, as in a constraint, view definition, etc?  What happens if you change the data type first and then rename?

Comment: The problem is with one column only, if I create a new column  it works fine. any ideas? I even restarted the server and still get this "invalid state" error when I try to rename that specific column.

Comment: Again, is the column you’re modifying referenced in a constraint, foreign key or view definition?

Comment: no, it's not referenced anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always give your Db2-server platform (z/os, linux/unix/windows, i series) and Db2-server version when asking for Db2-help, because the answer can depend on these facts.

The exception  SQL20054N reason 23, means that the table has reached a limit on the number of alterations  and before continuing, the table need to be reorganized with a [REORG](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001966.html) command.  The documentation for the error is [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/sql20000-sql20249.html#sql20054n). The REORG command will put the table back into a normal state. Normally a DBA would consider running [RUNSTATS](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001980.html) command following the REORG to ensure that table statistics are refreshed following the alterations.

Db2-LUW allows a small number of table changes (often 3) before forcing a reorg for certain kinds of alterations. Previous alterations to this table might have been performed by others, in different transactions , without getting this exception.  Schema-evolution tools should detect this state and recover from it.

This is a normal situation, and the recovery is to run the REORG command.

You can either ask your DBA to do reorg for you, or you can (if your authid has the correct permissions) from jdbc call a stored procedure `admin_cmd()` to perform the command for you, or just use the Db2 command line interface `reorg table db.t1 inplace` for example .   The documentation for `admin_cmd` is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023582.html), and if you do not understand the REORG details, ask your DBA for help.